# Delete simulated text messages in the iOS 10 simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios10

Is it possible to delete simulated text messages in the iOS 10 simulators?  There isn't an edit button in the main Messages view on the simulator and swipe to delete doesn't seem to work either.  Messages clears simulated messages after ending a session with an app but I'm trying to create a mockup for a screenshot and delete an individual simulated text I mistyped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold down on the message, a box comes up. Click on more and it allows you to select messages to delete. It took me a while to figure it out!